# Abnormal Receiving of Google Verification Codes

Tags: email, multi-factor, google, gmail

Recently I have been receiving "Google Verification Codes" that I never requested and for password recovery of the google accounts that are not mine however are similar to mine. It might be possible that a user added a wrong email address (mine) as his/her recovery email, however, the frequency of receiving these emails and in different time spans is suspicious and makes me wonder if there would be another explanation. Could this be an attempt to hack me in some way? if yes how? I cannot think of any way.

P.S. Yesterday I received two verification codes one for a google account and before that one for a Microsoft account (apparently a Gmail that is used as a Microsoft account).

P.P.S. Google two-factor authentication is active.

Comment: Did you check the activity on your google profile? Do you see any suspicious login attempts there?

Comment: @GACy20 I don't think if login attempts get reported in the google security activity. If you mean changing passwords or logged-in device all is normal. Indeed what I tried to explain in the question is kind of the contary, that is I might be able to attemp to login to that email address with the verification code.

Comment: Are you sure these messages are from Google and not someone pretending to be Google?

Comment: @Laurel good point! But yes I am sure they are from noreply@google

Comment: I don't know about gmail, but microsoft logs attempts and you can see it in the security pages in your account.

Comment: If its indeed an incorrect email address entry, then its understandable that the frequency is increasing.  The poor person is unable to log in and he keeps trying again and again !!!!

Answer (score 3):

**No, I do not see a potential security risk for your account**.

Those two step verification codes are used for login purposes and to be entered after supplying the password. You won't be able to do anything without the password, and the password won't help much without those codes. Usually there are backup codes exactly for this purpose (unable to retrieve the sent codes), but in case whoever set this up did not write those down.. Things like that happen. As your email is probably noted as recovery address now, you get password recovery notifications as well (after the person realized the dumpster fire it created).

**As long as it ain't your account, there is no indication of compromise**. Someone apparently screwed up big time with his account. What to do about it? I do not know about Microsoft, but in Google emails there should be a link to unsubscribe from notifications about the account.

Comment: Thanks, well I fully agree with you answer and this was my understanding as well, I wanted to be sure though, beacuse it seems that MORE THAN ONE PERSON screwed up big time with their account! but I guess that happens !!! I already unsubscribed from some of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing this as well (I received 21 emails between 7:36 - 10:11 am today, some in Arabic). They are usually accompanied by "Someone added you as their recovery email" from no-reply@accounts.google.com.

That email says:
"If you don’t recognize this account, it’s likely your email address was added in error. You can remove your email address from that account. *Disconnect email*"

While normal phishing warnings apply, you can use the *Disconnect email* link to make sure that the email is no longer connected to your account. I don't know if it helps, but I've been doing it each time, after verifying that the email did come from Google.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Ugh, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that "Disconnect email" link might be the actual phishing...